# Flexbox and animation without js

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have to create a flexbox that look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojXYs.png).

I need a 4x4 flex box (wit the corner empty), an img in each item. whenever i hover an image, i have to put an animation in the "animation" section (see the pic).
I tried to use sibling connector, but it doesn't work cause the vertical and the horizontal item aren't siblings.
Does anyone know how i can connect div that have different parent. (sorry if my english is not the best)

If needed, here is the actual code (sorry if it doesn't look good i'm learning)

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 25%;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 500%;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.flex-container2>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 500%;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.flex-container3 {
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  width: 73%;
  line-height: 3900%;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container3>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: auto;
  font-size: 30px;
}

@keyframes anim1 {
  from {
    background-color: red;
  }
  to {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}

#img1:hover~#anim {
  animation-name: anim1;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div>empty</div>
    <div id="img1">1</div>
    <div id="img2">2</div>
    <div id="img3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container3">
    <div id="anim">animation</div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-container2">
    <div id="img4">4</div>
    <div id="img5">5</div>
    <div id="img6">6</div>
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Please show the code that you tryed.

Comment: i just added it.

Comment: Are you trying to move each image into the animation area when hovering?

Comment: basically, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged the html and took away a lot of your styles, but it works. Instead of using a flexbox for a complicated layout like this, I used CSS grid.

It activates the animation when `.img1` is hover on.

I hope this helps!

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: "empty img1 img2 img3" "img4 anim anim anim" "img5 anim anim anim" "img6 anim anim anim";
}

div:not(.container) {
  border: 5px solid #005A9C;
  text-align: center;
}

.empty {
  grid-area: empty;
}

.img1 {
  grid-area: img1;
}

.img2 {
  grid-area: img2;
}

.img3 {
  grid-area: img3;
}

.anim {
  grid-area: anim;
}

.img4 {
  grid-area: img4;
}

.img5 {
  grid-area: img5;
}

.img6 {
  grid-area: img6;
}

@keyframes anim1 {
  from {
    background-color: red;
  }
  to {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}

.img1:hover~.anim {
  animation-name: anim1;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="empty">empty</div>
  <div class="img1">1</div>
  <div class="img2">2</div>
  <div class="img3">3</div>
  <div class="anim">anim</div>
  <div class="img4">4</div>
  <div class="img5">5</div>
  <div class="img6">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, if you want to move the image (`.img1`) into the anim box, I can show that too!

Comment: thanks a lot for your time, but the flexbox is mandatory in this exercise. And that's the whole problem.
But i'd appreciate if you could show me how to move an img without having this "glitch" effect when it just go and come back. I don't know if you get what i mean.